SwiftUI TabView sometimes navigates wrong
I'm working on a SwiftUI application that uses a TabView with multiple tabs. When there are too many tabs to display, a 'More' option appears to handle the overflow. I've encountered an issue where selecting the first item in the 'More' menu doesn't navigate to the correct view—instead, it opens the first tab in the main tab bar. Interestingly, this first tab in the 'More' menu includes an API request that executes successfully, indicating that the view is being loaded, but the UI still navigates to the wrong tab.
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selectedTab = 0
    @State private var visibleTabs: [TabItem] = []
    @State private var previousTab = 0

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {
                    ForEach(visibleTabs) { tab in
                        tab.view
                            .tabItem {
                                Label(tab.title, systemImage: tab.icon)
                            }
                            .tag(tab.id)
                    }
                }
                .onChange(of: selectedTab) { oldValue, newValue in
                    if oldValue != newValue {
                        previousTab = newValue
                    }
                }
            }
            .onAppear {
                updateVisibleTabs()
                // Ensure selectedTab is valid
                if !visibleTabs.contains(where: { $0.id == selectedTab }) {
                    selectedTab = visibleTabs.first?.id ?? 0
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private func updateVisibleTabs() {
        visibleTabs = allTabs
    }

    private var allTabs: [TabItem] {
        [
            TabItem(id: 0, title: "Tab One", icon: "1.circle", view: AnyView(TabOneView())),
            TabItem(id: 1, title: "Tab Two", icon: "2.circle", view: AnyView(TabTwoView())),
            TabItem(id: 2, title: "Tab Three", icon: "3.circle", view: AnyView(TabThreeView())),
            TabItem(id: 3, title: "Tab Four", icon: "4.circle", view: AnyView(TabFourView())),
            TabItem(id: 4, title: "Tab Five", icon: "5.circle", view: AnyView(TabFiveView())),
            TabItem(id: 5, title: "Tab Six", icon: "6.circle", view: AnyView(TabSixView())),
            TabItem(id: 6, title: "Tab Seven", icon: "7.circle", view: AnyView(TabSevenView()))
        ]
    }
}

struct TabItem: Identifiable {
    let id: Int
    let title: String
    let icon: String
    let view: AnyView
}

struct TabOneView: View {
    @State private var data: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Tab One")
                .font(.largeTitle)
            Text("Data: \(data)")
                .padding()
        }
        .onAppear {
            fetchData()
        }
    }

    private func fetchData() {
        // Simulated API request
        let url = URL(string: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1")!
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
            if let data = data,
            let todo = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Todo.self, from: data) {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.data = todo.title
                }
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}

struct Todo: Decodable {
    let id: Int
    let title: String
    let completed: Bool
}

// Dummy views for other tabs
struct TabTwoView: View { var body: some View { Text("Tab Two") } }
struct TabThreeView: View { var body: some View { Text("Tab Three") } }
struct TabFourView: View { var body: some View { Text("Tab Four") } }
struct TabFiveView: View { var body: some View { Text("Tab Five") } }
struct TabSixView: View { var body: some View { Text("Tab Six") } }
struct TabSevenView: View { var body: some View { Text("Tab Seven") } }

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}

The TabView uses an Int for selectedTab and unique integer ids for each TabItem.
The first tab (TabOneView) makes an API request to a placeholder API (jsonplaceholder.typicode.com), which is a common testing endpoint.
The issue occurs when selecting the first item in the 'More' menu; it doesn't navigate to the correct view, even though the API request in TabOneView is executed successfully.
Has anyone experienced a similar issue with TabView and the 'More' menu in SwiftUI?
Is there a known workaround or solution to ensure that selecting the first item in the 'More' menu navigates to the correct view?
Could the problem be related to how TabView handles selection and view updates when tabs overflow into the 'More' section?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Default tab view should always be at the very top, each tab gets its own NavigationView/Stack. Also AnyView is highly discouraged views don’t belong in models.

As loremipsum has already correctly written, a TabView should never be inside a NavigationView. Don't forget that SwiftUI still uses UITaBbarController and UINavigationController behind the scenes. And even though Apple's documentation is weak in this regard, it is mentioned here and indirectly here.
